# How can I use the Visual module? - Python

Tags: python

Since not a long ago, I've entered the Python 3D game development course. Today's homework is to do some research about the `Visual` module. But when I actually search it on internet, it all it shows is the following.

> Download Visual Studio Code. Click here to enter the site.

Is there anybody who knows how to use the `Visual` module? All the code my teacher provided me is the following.

```
#Modules
from visual import *

#Script
"""
Write your code here!
"""
```

Thank you.

Comment: A search for “Python visual module” returns a first result for [VPython](https://vpython.org/), and nothing relating to Visual Studio. What’s your question, exactly? [ask]

Comment: Ask your teacher what they mean by "the Visual module". Is it a module that is provided by the teacher of your course?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code writing service. We can help with specific problems in your code, but we don't do your homework for you. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Classic VPython" import statement: `from visual import *` is obsolete and no longer works in the latest versions of VPython. The latest versions of Vpython use the import statement `from vpython import *` and there are also some syntax changes between the new vpython and the older "Classic VPython".

Ask your teacher if you are expected to install an older version of Python for this assignment. In order to not interfere with your existing Python installation you should install the required packages for your homework assignment in a sandboxed virtualenv (`python3 -m pip3 install virtualenv`) Python virtual environment. It's also easier to install Python packages with pip when you're starting off in a fresh, clean Python virtual environment.

Comment: You can also write and run VPython programs, without installing any software, by going to webvpython.org. While there, click "Help" for full documentation, including tutorials. Or, if you are to use the vpython module with installed Python, go to vpython.org for installation instructions

Comment: Ty for actually answering this question